# Sorting a HTML table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm using the following function to sort a HTML table in JavaScript:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
  return (a[column] == b[column]) ? 0 : ((a[column] > b[column]) ? order : -1*order);
});
```

However it doesn't recognize small or capital letters and displays capital letters from A-Z first and then small letters from a-z. How could I improve the function, to have both of them mixed alphabetically?

Comment: Rather than comparing `a[column]`, compare `a[column].toLowerCase()`?

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Also didn't notice that this question had been asked already.